# Duplicatehandle with inheritedhandles

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following flow:

1. Process A:

   - Creates a usertoken.
   - Creates a suspended process
   - Duplicates the usertoken created in step above using DuplicateHandle and passes bInherithandle to true.
   - Resumes the child process
   - Sends the duplicatehandle to the child process
2. Child Process B:

   - Receives the handle sent by the parent process and stores it as a Handle (a global variable).
   - !handle shows the handle and !lsaexts.dumptoken dumps all the SID information. So the handle is valid.
   - Calls createprocess with bInheritHandle = true
3. Child Process C: (Spawned by B)

   - I don’t see the handle with !handle
   - If I try !handle or !lsaexts.dumptoken with the specific handle value from B I get error that its invalid

What am I doing wrong here?

As per MSDN documentation, if the process is spawned using binheritedhandles set to true then the child process should be able to use every handle in the parent process which was created with binheritedhandles set to true during its creation.

Comment: You do "send" the handle value to process C, do you?

Comment: Yes by adding the handle value from B to the environment block while creating process C and the child process C reads the handle value from the environment variable. But that handle value is invalid in the child process C.

Comment: The question says that A creates the inheritable handle *after* launching B, so B shouldn't have a copy of the handle in the first place.  Looks like the OP is no longer active on SO, so I'm voting to close as unclear.